# How can a vector space be closed under scalar multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, universal-algebra

A set is closed under an operation if performing the operation on members of the set always produces a member of the set. In fact, any algebraic structure must be closed under the operations that define it. So if a given vector space $V_1$ is closed under a binary operation $T$, it must be $T: V_1 \times V1 \to V_1$.

It is said that vector spaces are closed under the operations of scalar multiplication (i.e., multiplication with an element of a field $F$).

A scalar multiplications on $V_1$ would be a map $T_1: V_1 \times F \to V_1$. This is not how we stated **closed** binary operations should work like, since it’s not $T: V_1 \times V_1 \to V_1$.

There are two ways to solve this:

1. You could consider scalar multiplication to be a unary operation taking its input from the vector space (intuitively, we “absorb the scalar inside the function”). In this case, any vector space would have only one binary operation (the addition), and **a whole set** of unary operations: the scalar multiplications. For each given scalar a of the field, there would be a unary function $F: V_1 \to V_1$ such that $F(v) = a \times v$.
   It works, but the cost is that you cannot say anymore that a general vector space has only 2 operations, and you cannot say anymore that scalar multiplication is a binary map.
2. You could still consider the scalar multiplication as a binary map, but in order to satisfy the closed-operation requirement stated at the beginning, you must re-define the structure as the union of the set of vectors and of the set of scalars. Is this what we do? If yes, consider a set of vectors $V_1$ defined on a field $F$: when we say “vector space” are we referring to the set $V_1$ or the union set ($V_1$ and $F$)? And with which title can we refer to the other set?

So which one is it? Is scalar multiplication a unary-map, or is the actual algebraic structure (closed under scalar multiplication) the set of vectors + field elements?
**And most importantly: do you have sources?**

Comment: This is just semantics.  So, scalar multiplication is not generally a binary operation.  It is, however, a map from $\mathbb F \times V\to V$ so just think of it that way.  You can even speak of it as the action of the scalar field $\mathbb F$ on the set $V$.  Groups act on sets all the time, that's not an unusual concept.

Comment: @lulu I don't think it's semantics anymore when you move to more abstract and fundamental branches of mathematics, such as universal algebra (and category theory and so on). In universal algebra, when talking about homomorphisms between algebras etc, you MUST know what the arities of your *fundamental operations* are. And fundamental operations are **closed**!

Comment: Category theory has no problem with group actions.  Why would you think that it did?

Comment: In universal algebra, the fundamental operations f defining an algebra A are closed, that is, f: $A^n → A$. If it's a fundamental operation, it must take each of its arguments from the algebra.

At the same time, a homomorphism maps fundamental operations of same arity between algebras. Therefore you need to know precisely the arities of your algebras' fundamental operations.

Comment: Only if you insist on using that language, which is not necessary. And even if you do so insist, you can just speak of a family of operations, one for each scalar. It's a bit artificial but it gets the job done.

Comment: that's why my question was legit as opposite to what the downvoters superficially thought. In that situation, the answer seems then to be the way #1 outlined in the question

Comment: Your question is phrased argumentatively, for no clear reason.  Vector space theory has been around for a long time, and people are quite comfortable considering scalar multiplication as a map from $\mathbb F\times V\to V$.  The only problem arises if you try to shoe horn the old language into the new one.  There isn't any controversy here.  Most mathematicians are indifferent to (or unaware of) the language of universal algebra.  And, if you want to do the shoehorning, it's not especially difficult.

Comment: but universal algebra was the reason why i asked this. my focus here was on the branch of foundations of mathematics; in this very specific case, the context of the question was how to derive vector space theory from more fundamental (and universal) mathematical elements. in the process i got stuck on the point outlined in this question, so i asked it here

Comment: You don't even refer to universal algebra in your post.  I think you would have gotten a better response had the title been something like "Is it possible to define vector spaces in the language of universal  algebra, and if so how is this usually done?"  People did, after all, study "algebraic structures" centuries before anyone thought of universal algebras.

Comment: the thing is, as outlined it my question, it is not necessary to refer to universal algebra to see that there is a contradiction between (I) saying that scalar multiplication is a binary map and (II) saying that vector space V is closed under scalar multiplication (where closure means $V^n→V$)

Comment: ...of course you are totally free to say "(I)", but logic forbids you to simultaneously say "(II)".

Comment: That second hypothesis you consider doesn't seem to make sense. If you want to have scalar multiplication as a binary operation, then it must be of the many-sorted type (in this case, many=2), in which you don't have an underlying set but a family of them (in this case, $(\mathbb F, V)$). See [many-sorted structure](https://planetmath.org/manysortedstructure), and have it without relational symbols, as there it is considered, in the examples, the case of modules over a ring (vector spaces over fields are a special case of these).

Answer (score 6):

If you insist that binary operations should have both arguments in the same set, then scalar multiplication is not a binary operation. Just give it another name if you want. It's often referred to as an *external* operation. It truly doesn't matter, there is actually no rule that all algebraic operations should be internal to a single set (a counter-example being... vector spaces).

Comment: I never wrote that **binary operations** must have both arguments in the same set. I quoted the universal saying that, in algebraic structures, **closed operations** must have both arguments in the same set.

Comment: and there is definitely a rule that states that any algebraic operation (defining an algebraic structure) must be closed, and therefore must take each argument from the structure

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to shoehorn in a semantically consistent interpretation, then you can say that scalar multiplication is a unary operation on the vector space, parameterised by a value taken from the underlying field. In other words, the operation is given by the family of functions $f_\alpha : V \rightarrow V$ with the parameter $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}$.

Under this interpretation, given any $\alpha$, the vector space $V$ is closed under $f_\alpha$.

**As it so happens**, you can directly link the family of unary operators $\{f_\alpha\}$ to the binary operation of scalar multiplication as it is typically defined. In fact, the map $\alpha \rightarrow f_\alpha$ is both bijective and linear in all the ways we'd want it to be.